# Using SSH, transfer webURL to remote machine

Tags: ssh, unix, terminal, shell, script

Hi so i was doing some research in the library so i could use some pictures later on my Desktop computer in my room. I have space on my Lab account which i usually SSH into, and i was wondering if URL's can be directly transferred over to a remote machine and saved on the hard disk.

I was thinking something like this:

```
scp http://click.si.edu/images/truncatedurl.jpg /home3/etc.../filename.jpg
```

is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this.  Basically you grab the contents and pipe it into a remote file using ssh.  This will work best if you have key-based authentication setup, so you don't have to provide your credentials during the copy process.

```
curl "http://click.si.edu/images/truncatedurl.jpg" | \
  ssh remotehost 'cat > /home3/etc.../filename.jpg'
```

Comment: lol i got reported for trying to install curl on the lab machines. Can i install it on my machine and have it work?

Comment: what about wget http://click.si.edu/images/truncatedurl.jpg -O file.jpg && scp file.jpg login@server:/home3/etc.../filename.jpg

Comment: If you have remote access to your home machine why don't you simply ssh to the remote machine and run wget/curl from there?